# Xamarin android. Works in debug. Doesn't work in release (createSubDecor null reference)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Application works in debug mode without `shared runtime` option and with `link sdk and user assemblies`
In release mode it doesn't work. Tried different link options and enabling `shared runtime`

I am using 23.4.0.1 android.support library

Here is log:

> java.lang.NullPointerException 09-17 21:25:33.987 I/MonoDroid( 3557):
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:491)
>   09-17 21:25:33.987 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
>   09-17 21:25:33.987 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
>   09-17 21:25:33.991 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   09-17 21:25:33.991 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   md5cc34a7196a93e5e13d1bb5964f64c350.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method) 09-17 21:25:33.991 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   md5cc34a7196a93e5e13d1bb5964f64c350.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
>   09-17 21:25:33.991 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 09-17
>   21:25:33.995 I/MonoDroid( 3557):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   09-17 21:25:33.995 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   09-17 21:25:33.995 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   09-17 21:25:33.995 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 09-17
>   21:25:33.995 I/MonoDroid( 3557):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   09-17 21:25:33.995 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 09-17
>   21:25:33.999 I/MonoDroid( 3557):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 09-17 21:25:33.999
>   I/MonoDroid( 3557):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 09-17
>   21:25:33.999 I/MonoDroid( 3557):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-17
>   21:25:33.999 I/MonoDroid( 3557):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 09-17 21:25:33.999
>   I/MonoDroid( 3557):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   09-17 21:25:33.999 I/MonoDroid( 3557):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 09-17
>   21:25:33.999 I/MonoDroid( 3557):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):
>   Process: com.SlaveryGames.PhoneChecker, PID: 3557 09-17 21:25:34.011
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.SlaveryGames.PhoneChecker/md5cc34a7196a93e5e13d1bb5964f64c350.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3557):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 09-17
>   21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 09-17
>   21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 09-17 21:25:34.011
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 09-17
>   21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-17
>   21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 09-17 21:25:34.011
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 09-17
>   21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-17 21:25:34.011
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3557): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:491)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   md5cc34a7196a93e5e13d1bb5964f64c350.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method) 09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   md5cc34a7196a93e5e13d1bb5964f64c350.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 09-17
>   21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   09-17 21:25:34.011 E/AndroidRuntime( 3557):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

Comment: Post your `OnCreate` method for your `MainActivity` and which version of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` are you using?

Comment: I added version of support library. About onCreate - There is nothing special there. I tried to remove everything from it but still crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Android Bug : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207638

- Compat 23.1.1, 23.3.0, 23.2.1, 23.3.0

#### Workaround (access `Window.DecorView` before `base.OnCreate` is called):

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207638
        #pragma warning disable CS0219
        var bugWorkAround = Window.DecorView.Handle;
        #pragma warning restore CS0219
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ~~~~~
```

#### Fixed(?) in 23.4.0.1+:

Note: I am still using the workaround in this version...

```
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

Note: Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659715/intermittent-nullpointerexception-from-appcompatdelegateimplv7-createsubdecor) as this is where i first found the Android bug number when I was getting CreateSubDecor null reference crashes.

Comment: @Vorotnyak_Nazar Glad to hear it... that Android issue caused a client a lot of issues in the field.

Answer (score 0):

For me, downgrading the support libraries worked for me. Perhaps reinstalling the new ones might work, haven't tried it. Took me 6 hours.